# How to make WPF ComboBox items background Visible?

Tags: wpf, combobox, background-color

```
  <Grid Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1">

      <ComboBox Cursor="Hand" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRealEstate}" Background="White"  
                 Name="cbbRealEstates"  ItemsSource="{Binding RealEstateSummary}"/>

   </Grid>
```

the code above gives me invisible item background

[image]

How do I make the background visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/332e6532-3a91-48f3-bb36-cad635f32a26/how-to-style-comboboxitem-foreground-color?forum=wpf),

You will have to set the styles in the resources of the element. In my case it's a window. So it's

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle" TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Set a style for `ComboBoxItem`. And use that style when you set the style for the `ComboBox`

Then apply the Combobox Style to the element.

```
<ComboBox Name="myCmb" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}">
```